# How to get OBD2 Fuel Level reading from Wagon R 2010 model

Tags: obd-ii

I want to measure current  fuel level inside my car's fuel tank using OBD2 bluetooth/USB adapter.

When i try to query that PID i got following data as "NO DATA" while at the same time i can check other PIDS like RPM and all data comes fine.

I have small python program which reads its but i am unable to get it.

```
import serial

#ser = serial.Serial('COM12',38400,timeout=1)
#ser.write("01 2F \r")
#speed_hex = ser.readline().split(' ')
#print speed_hex
#convert hex to decprint ("SpeedHex",speed_hex)
#speed = float(int('0x'+speed_hex[3],0))
#print ('Speed',speed,'Km/h')
ser1 = serial.Serial("COM12",38400,timeout=1)
#ser1.write("ATZ \r")
#ser1.write("ATE0 \r")
#ser1.write("ATL0 \r")
#ser1.write("ATH1 \r")
#ser1.write("ATSP 5 \r")
ser1.write("01 0C \r")
fuel_hex= ser1.readline()
print fuel_hex
#convert to hex to decprint ("FuelHex",fuel_hex)
#fuel = float(int('0x'+fuel_hex[3],0))
#print ("Fuel in Per",fuel)
```

Can any one suggest here how to get fuel level which is their inside in car at this current time. As i can see in my panel with bar sign.

Comment: As i know for some cars these data may not be visible using the OBD2 is there any method available for calculate current fuel level in car ...

Comment: You can find out which PIDs are supported by your can with testing the PID 0x00, 0x20, 0x40 and etc. It will response with 4 bytes which each bit shows you the availability of that PID. Then you can have a plan how to get your fuel level.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mogi Could you please show me quick example for how can i put in OBD2 code i am guessing pids which you have mention in your comment are mode 1. Could you please verify it.

Comment: I have written in answers. Maybe it helps. I cannot write you a code since I've no Python experience but tried to explain it to you. Don't hesitate to vote it up :=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get all the available PIDs in a vehicle, you have to request the following PIDs at first exactly like you ask the rpm of the vehicle:

`0x00`, `0x20`, `0x40`, ....`0x80` and so on.

For instance when you request PID `0x00` the ECU will return you 4 bytes which means if it supports PIDs from `0x01 - 0x20`. Each byte has 8 bits in total of 32 bits which is exactly from PID `0x01` to PID `0x20`. Now it is time to parse the data. If each bit is 1 it means the ECU will support and 0 no support. It is your duty to do some bitwise operations to translate these bits:

Also you can look out this [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OBD-II_PIDs#Mode_1_PID_00) which shows in graphics!

byte 1 bit 1 : availability of PID `0x01`

byte 1 bit 2 : availability of PID `0x02`

byte 1 bit 3 : availability of PID `ox03`

....

byte 4 bit 7 : availability of PID `0x1F`

byte 4 bit 8 : availability of PID `0x20` --> Here the ECU tells you if support any PIDs in next 32 PIDs. If it is 0, you do not need to check anymore!

After parsing and gathering all the supported PIDs, then you can have a roadmap to calculate or check each PIDs you want. Do not forget many of conversion rates a formulas in wikipedia is wrong due to the complexity of calculations. You have to read the [ISO 15031 part 5](https://www.iso.org/standard/66368.html) and do NOT forget ECU only gives you the emissions-related diagnostics and not all the data.